# How to validate a string which can contain numbers spaces, + and - using regex php

Tags: php, regex, validation

I want to validate phone numbers like follows using php.

+009411774132482
011 2560-205

Comment: Do you know which [numbering plans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbering_plan) you need to support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one   `'/^\+?[0-9 \-]+$/'`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it...

```
preg_match('/^\+?[\d -]+\z/', $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HwWY35).

It will allow...

- An optional preceding `+`.
- More than one of digits (`0-9`), space and `-`. If you want a minimum amount, swap the `+` with `{9,}`.
- Does not allow a trailing `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
^[\d\s+-]+$
```